# Jquery Validation with multiple textboxes with same name and corresponding checkboxes with same name

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

How can I add Jquery Validation for multiple textboxes with same name, when their corresponding checkboxes are checked

```
    Jquery:
     $("input:[name='abc']").change(function() {
                var method = $(this).val();
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $("#" + method).spinner({
                        'disabled': false
                    });
                    console.log(method);
                    $("#" + method).rules("add",{
                            range: [1, 99],
                            required : true,
                            messages: {
                                    range: "Please enter a value between 1 and 99",
                                    required: "Please give a value for " + method
                            }
                    });
                    $("#" + method).val(1);
                } else {
                    $("#" + method).spinner({
                        'disabled': true
                    });
                    console.log(method);
                    $("#" + method).rules('remove','range');
                    $("#" + method).rules('remove','required');
                    $("#" + method).val(0);
                }
            });
```

Trying to add and remove rules to textboxes depending upon the checkbox change event.

Comment: Why not have unique names?

Comment: Since I am doing both front-end and back-end validation, There is a necessity to validate with names. Back-end validation is happening with perl

Comment: Can you include the code for what you have done. So we could look more into the issue.And have a clear picture of what you are attempting to do.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV, the jQuery Validate plugin mandates that all fields considered for validation have a unique name.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I add jQuery Validation for **multiple textboxes with same name** ...

You can **not** use [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) for this.

This plugin internally uses the `name` attribute to keep track of all form elements, therefore, all `name` attribute values **must** be unique.  There is no workaround to this hard-coded requirement.